# What has been sent in POST?

Tags: firefox, post, browser

I have a form on a web page. When I click the Submit button, the browser sends the form data within a POST request. If I refresh the result then it sends the data again.

I want to see what the POST data was *without* re-sending the form. How can I do it?

I know, there is the Developer Tools dialog which can show me what requests are being sent to the server. But, in order to analyze a request, I need to turn the DT on *before* I send the request. So, if I want to see what the POST content *was*, I need to send the form again, which I wanted to avoid.

I am sure that the browser knows what content of the POST was because if I refresh the result page, it will send the same POST data again. How can I access this information?

I would like to know the answer how to do it in Firefox but I am interested in Chrome as well.